# Reading values from a file and using classes

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, fstream

Hi I'm having trouble with filling the values of 2 private class members from an input file which is called money.txt . Can you please tell me why it only reads the first value of the file (after the size which is declared on the first line) and then doesn't read the rest of the values? If my method isn't the best approach can you recommend another method to solve this ?

Here is the **money.h** file:

```cpp
#ifndef money_h
#define money_h
class Money{
public:
    void getdollars();
    void getcents();
    void printdollars();
    void printcents();
private:
    int dollars[3];
    int cents[3];
};
#endif
```

Here's the **implementation.cpp**

```cpp
#include"money.h"
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
    ifstream instream;
void Money::getdollars()
{
    instream.open("money.txt");
    int s;
    instream>>s;
    instream>>dollars[0];
    instream>>dollars[1];
    instream>>dollars[2];
}
void Money:: getcents()
{
    instream.open("money.txt");
    int s;  
    instream>>s;
    instream>>cents[0];
    instream>>cents[1];
    instream>>cents[2];
}
void Money:: printdollars()
{
    cout<<*dollars;
}
void Money:: printcents()
{
    cout<<*cents;
}
```

Here are the **main.cpp** and **money.txt** files

```cpp
#include"money.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

Money** readMoney(Money** &x , char* filename)
{
    int size;
    ifstream instream;
    instream.open(filename);
    instream>>size;
    x = new Money*[size];
    for(int i = 0;i<size;i++)
    {
        x[i] = new Money[size];
        for(int j = 0;j<size;j++)
        {
        x[i][j].getdollars();
        x[i][j].getcents();
        }
    }
    return x;

}
void printmoney(Money **a,int size)
{
    ifstream instream;
    int i = 0 , j = 0;
    while(i<size && j<size)
    {
    a[i][j].printdollars();
    cout<<" ";
    a[i][j].printcents();
    cout<<endl;
    j++;
    }
}
void main()
{
    Money** test;
    ifstream instream;
    readMoney(test,"money.txt");
    printmoney(test,3);
}
```

Money.txt

```
3
5 60
2 30
3 21
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a quick look it seems that the code opens the file "money.txt" three times. The first time in the function `readMoney`, the second time in `getdollars` and the third time in `getcents`. Probably this the problem. Open the file only once in `readMoney` function and pass the opened stream to the instance of `Money`.

Comment: What do you mean pass it the open stream? And if i open it once in readMoney , How would i read the values in getmoney and getcents functions without opening the file?

Comment: You can use `>>` once the file is opened: you don't need t keep reopening it.

Comment: Pass it as the function parameter, for example. `MoneyInstance.getdollars(instream);`. Then `getdollars` will use this parameter and read from it into the private class members `dollars`

Comment: So the getdollars function should look like this?

 void getdollars(ifstream instream);

Comment: It's better to pass the stream by reference, that is `Money::getdollars(ifstream& instream)`

Answer (score 1):

When you open a file, it starts reading from the beginning by default.

You can `seek` to other places, but this is not needed in your case.

If you make the `ifstream instream;` a member of the class, and pass in the filename, it can open the file in the constructor and deserialise there. (Or in you `get` functions if you must).

Otherwise you could open the file in `main` and let the `get` functions take a input stream.

Either way open the file once and allow each read to leave the next read point ready for you.

---

*Edit:*

Just as an example, if you send the stream into the `get` functions as something more general, like `istream` this allows you to send in stringstream or other stream types.

```
void Money::getdollars(istream &file)
{
    int s;  
    file>>s;
    file>>dollars[0];
    file>>dollars[1];
    file>>dollars[2];
}
//... and similarly for other functions
//...
#include "money.h"
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    Money money;
    std::stringstream stream("3\n5 60\n2 30\n3 21");
    money.getdollars(stream);
}
```

Note taking it by reference `istream &file` so the state can change.